# Gas estimation failed: 'invalid opcode: INVALID'. This transaction will likely revert. If you wish to broadcast, you must set the gas limit manually

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, brownie

I adapted the code from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p36tXHX1JD8&t=5254s) for my needs. It works fine at rinkeby network, but I am getting an error when I try to run it on Mumbai network.

AdvancedCollectible.sol >>

```
pragma solidity 0.6.6;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol";


contract AdvancedCollectible is ERC721 {

    bytes32 internal keyHash;
    uint256 public fee;
    event requestedCollectible(address indexed senderAdd);

    uint256 public tokenCounter;

    struct Remedio { 
      string nome_medicamento;
      uint256 dosagem;
      string farmaceutica;
      string posologia;
   }   


    enum Breed{PUG, SHIBA_INU, ST_BERNARD}
    mapping(uint256 => address) public requestIdToSender;
    mapping(uint256 => Breed) public tokenIdToBreed;
    mapping(uint256 => Remedio) public tokenIdToRemedio;
    mapping(uint256 => uint256) public requestIdToTokenId;

    

    constructor() public
        ERC721("GeradorReceitasMedicas", "Receita")
    {
        
        tokenCounter = 0;
    }

    

    function createCollectible(string memory nomeMedicamento, uint256 dosagem, string memory farmaceutica, string memory posologia) 
    public returns (bytes32) {
        
        uint256 newItemId = tokenCounter;

        tokenCounter = tokenCounter + 1;

        Remedio memory newRemedio = Remedio({
           nome_medicamento: nomeMedicamento,
           dosagem: dosagem,
           farmaceutica: farmaceutica,
           posologia: 'posologia'
        });

        requestIdToSender[newItemId] = msg.sender;
        address receitaOwner = requestIdToSender[newItemId];

        _safeMint(receitaOwner, newItemId);

        tokenIdToRemedio[newItemId] = newRemedio;

        emit requestedCollectible(receitaOwner);

    }
    
    

}
```

LinkTokenInterface.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

interface LinkTokenInterface {
  function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256 remaining);
  function approve(address spender, uint256 value) external returns (bool success);
  function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint256 balance);
  function decimals() external view returns (uint8 decimalPlaces);
  function decreaseApproval(address spender, uint256 addedValue) external returns (bool success);
  function increaseApproval(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) external;
  function name() external view returns (string memory tokenName);
  function symbol() external view returns (string memory tokenSymbol);
  function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256 totalTokensIssued);
  function transfer(address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool success);
  function transferAndCall(address to, uint256 value, bytes calldata data) external returns (bool success);
  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool success);
}
```

DeployAdvanced.py:

```
from brownie import AdvancedCollectible, accounts, network, config
from scripts.helpful_scripts import fund_advanced_collectible

def main():
    print(config['wallets']['from_key'])
    dev = accounts.add(config['wallets']['from_key'])
    print(network.show_active())
    #print(config['networks'][network.show_active()]['host'])
    publish_source = False
    print(config['wallets']['from_key'])
    advanced_collectible = AdvancedCollectible.deploy(
        {"from": dev},
        publish_source=publish_source,
    )

    fund_advanced_collectible(advanced_collectible)

    return advanced_collectible
```

helpful_scripts.py:

```
from brownie import AdvancedCollectible, accounts, config, interface, network



def fund_advanced_collectible(nft_contract):
    dev = accounts.add(config['wallets']['from_key'])
    link_token = interface.LinkTokenInterface(
        config['networks'][network.show_active()]['link_token']
    )
    link_token.transfer(nft_contract, 1000000000000000000, {"from": dev})
```

> brownie-config.yaml:
>
> ## exclude SafeMath when calculating test coverage
>
> ## https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/v1.10.3/config.html#exclude_paths
>
> reports:   exclude_contracts:
> - SafeMath dependencies:
>
> - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
> - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0 compiler:   solc:
>   remappings:
>
>   - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1'
>   - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0'
>
> ## automatically fetch contract sources from Etherscan autofetch_sources: True dotenv: .env
>
> ## set a custom mnemonic for the development network networks:   default: development   kovan:
>
> ```
> vrf_coordinator: '0xdD3782915140c8f3b190B5D67eAc6dc5760C46E9'
> link_token: '0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088'
> keyhash: '0x6c3699283bda56ad74f6b855546325b68d482e983852a7a82979cc4807b641f4'
> fee: 100000000000000000
> oracle: '0x2f90A6D021db21e1B2A077c5a37B3C7E75D15b7e'
> jobId: '29fa9aa13bf1468788b7cc4a500a45b8'
> eth_usd_price_feed: '0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331'   rinkeby:
> vrf_coordinator: '0xb3dCcb4Cf7a26f6cf6B120Cf5A73875B7BBc655B'
> link_token: '0x01be23585060835e02b77ef475b0cc51aa1e0709'
> keyhash: '0x2ed0feb3e7fd2022120aa84fab1945545a9f2ffc9076fd6156fa96eaff4c1311'
> fee: 100000000000000000
> oracle: '0x7AFe1118Ea78C1eae84ca8feE5C65Bc76CcF879e'
> jobId: '6d1bfe27e7034b1d87b5270556b17277'
> eth_usd_price_feed: '0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e'
> host: 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/${WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID}'   mumbai:
> link_token: '0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB'
> eth_usd_price_feed: '0x0715A7794a1dc8e42615F059dD6e406A6594651A'   polygon-test:
> link_token: '0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB'
> eth_usd_price_feed: '0x0715A7794a1dc8e42615F059dD6e406A6594651A'   binance:
> # link_token: ??
> eth_usd_price_feed: '0x9ef1B8c0E4F7dc8bF5719Ea496883DC6401d5b2e'   binance-fork:
> eth_usd_price_feed: '0x9ef1B8c0E4F7dc8bF5719Ea496883DC6401d5b2e'   mainnet-fork:
> eth_usd_price_feed: '0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419'   matic-fork:
> eth_usd_price_feed: '0xF9680D99D6C9589e2a93a78A04A279e509205945' wallets:   from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}   from_mnemonic: ${MNEMONIC}
> ```
>
> settings:   gas_limit: "100000000000"

When I run it on Rinkeby, I get (run command **brownie run .\scripts\advancedCollectible\deploy_advanced.py --network rinkeby**):

> INFORMAÇÕES: não foi possível localizar arquivos para o(s) padrão(ões)
> especificado(s). Brownie v1.18.1 - Python development framework for
> Ethereum
>
> ContratoNftProject is the active project.
>
> Running 'scripts\advancedCollectible\deploy_advanced.py::main'...
> rinkeby
> Transaction sent:
> 0xf3cbcf650ab9b4408f8e795469ffa60a61f5943ab485ec133e3650fece7545db
> Gas price: 1.499999222 gwei   Gas limit: 2377218   Nonce: 67
> AdvancedCollectible deployed at:
> 0x5D37fc76D54880F878a395755df5101B644B655a
>
> C:\Users\p\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py:1180:
> BrownieCompilerWarning: 0x5D37fc76D54880F878a395755df5101B644B655a:
> Locally compiled and on-chain bytecode do not match!   warnings.warn(
> Transaction sent:
> 0x74a64ac1449a597584bbca8dc0947e80a6ad042ca68453da6e550a0dbbfe67da
> Gas price: 1.499999221 gwei   Gas limit: 56992   Nonce: 68
> LinkToken.transfer confirmed   Block: 10631644   Gas used: 51811
> (90.91%)

When I run it on Mumbai, I get (run command **brownie run .\scripts\advancedCollectible\deploy_advanced.py --network polygon-test**):

> INFORMAÇÕES: não foi possível localizar arquivos para o(s) padrão(ões)
> especificado(s). Brownie v1.18.1 - Python development framework for
> Ethereum
>
> ContratoNftProject is the active project.
>
> Running 'scripts\advancedCollectible\deploy_advanced.py::main'...
> polygon-test
> Transaction sent:
> 0x6915605b9dfb985b8ef078e3268a6b6e6e2e0b95d3d25ce8e5912c7a71db84d7
> Gas price: 1.759579396 gwei   Gas limit: 2377218   Nonce: 13
> AdvancedCollectible.constructor confirmed   Block: 26234140   Gas
> used: 2161108 (90.91%)   AdvancedCollectible deployed at:
> 0xdbae4544699a953f2b28AFfBA77008Fd9eb1B4Cf
>
> File
> "C:\Users\p\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\brownie_cli\run.py",
> line 51, in main
> return_value, frame = run(   File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py",
> line 103, in run
> return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)   File ".\scripts\advancedCollectible\deploy_advanced.py", line 16, in main
> fund_advanced_collectible(advanced_collectible)   File ".\scripts\helpful_scripts.py", line 10, in fund_advanced_collectible
> link_token.transfer(nft_contract, 1000000000000000000, {"from": dev})   File
> "C:\Users\p\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py",
> line 1710, in **call**
> return self.transact(*args)   File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py",
> line 1583, in transact
> return tx["from"].transfer(   File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py",
> line 644, in transfer
> receipt, exc = self._make_transaction(   File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py",
> line 727, in _make_transaction
> raise VirtualMachineError(e) from None   File "C:\Users\p\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\brownie\exceptions.py",
> line 93, in **init**
> raise ValueError(str(exc)) from None ValueError: Gas estimation failed: 'invalid opcode: INVALID'. This transaction will likely
> revert. If you wish to broadcast, you must  set the gas limit
> manually.

Why am I getting this error on Mumbai Network? Is it possible to fix the error above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `brownie-config.yaml` defines a [link_token](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB) address on the Mumbai testnet. The `fund_advanced_collectible` Python function then tries to transfer this token from the `dev` address.

From other context of your post, I was able to find that the `dev` address is [0x7cc6FA028dffa310445af40C3abEea61F8534d97](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x7cc6FA028dffa310445af40C3abEea61F8534d97).

*Mind that you shared the private key as part of the debug output, but did not share the `dev` address directly (which I was still able to derive from the key). I'm not sure whether that was intentional on your part, but if there were crypto with monetary value on the same address on mainnet, anyone could steal it using this private key. So I'd recomend you to consider this address compromised and never use it on mainnet.*

Anyway, the `dev` address does not own any LINK tokens on Mumbai testnet, which makes this part of the script fail:

```
link_token.transfer(nft_contract, 1000000000000000000, {"from": dev})
```

You can claim testnet LINK tokens from the Chainlink faucet: https://faucets.chain.link/mumbai

Comment: It works now. Thanks for your answer. No wories... this address is just for testing indeed. Thanks mate. You helped me.